# How to create a proxy on an enum?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an `enum` that I would like to setup a `Proxy` for, however when I try to set the value of `this.status`, nothing happens. I am expecting `I have been set` to get output to the console but that doesn't happen. Why isn't the proxy working on an enum?

```
export enum Status { Beginning, Middle, Ending }

export class MyClass {
  public status = new Proxy(Status, {
    set: (target, propertyKey, value) = {
      console.log('I have been set')
      return Reflect.set(target, propertyKey, value)
    },
    get: (target, propertyKey) => Reflect.get(target, propertyKey)
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
let c = new MyClass
c.status = Status.Middle
```

When I try to set it, I get the following error:

> Type 'Status.Middle' is not assignable to type 'typeof Status'.

Comment: Think of how this would look without the proxy. `public status = Status` wouldn't make much sense, would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you don't actually want a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but [accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) for the `status` property of `MyClass` instead.  Like so:

```
export enum Status { Beginning, Middle, Ending }

export class MyClass {
  private target: Status = Status.Beginning;

  public get status(): Status {
    return this.target;
  }
  public set status(status: Status) {
    console.log("I have been set");
    this.target = status;
  }
}

let c = new MyClass();
c.status = Status.Middle;
// logs "I have been set".
```

The issues: if you want to intercept gets and sets on the `status` property of a `MyClass`, then you need to do the "proxy-like" behavior on `MyClass`, not on `Status`.  And if you are only trying to intercept gets and sets on a single known property, then a full Proxy is overkill, since you'd only be doing anything special when the `propertyKey` is equal to `status`... while accessors are specifically intended for wrapping single properties.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

If `private` isn't good enough for you, you can do this:

```
export class MyClass {
  status!: Status; // status will be defined in the constructor

  constructor() {
    let target = Status.Beginning;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'status', {
      get() { return target; },
      set(status: Status) {
        console.log("I have been set");
        target = status;
      }
    })
  }
}

let c = new MyClass();
c.status = Status.Middle;
// logs "I have been set".
```

which hides the underlying `target` in a closure, completely inaccessible to the outside world.  But note that you are essentially creating an "own" accessor on each instance of `MyClass`, instead of just one accessor on the `MyClass` prototype.  It's up to you if that matters.

Good luck again.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of doing it this way... The only issue is, that if the private property is changed, then the function won't be triggered...

Comment: That's why it's private.  If you absolutely need to protect target you can close over a local variable in the constructor function or use a proxy on `MyClass`.

Comment: edited a way of doing it that hides `target` completely